# If Field in Table is Blank don't reference

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to build a formula that reference cells in a table. My goal is to only return values that have data in the reference cells. So if a cell in the table is blank don't return it. Also it is not referencing the first row in my table. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Carrier Rules and Contact Info'!$A$A,SMALL(IF(('Volume Template'!$B$4>='Carrier Rules and Contact Info'!$B:$B)+('Volume Template'!$C$4>='Carrier Rules and Contact Info'!$C:$C),ROW('Carrier Rules and Contact Info'!$B:$B)),ROW('Carrier Rules and Contact Info'!2:2))),"")
```

How can I improve this formula?

Comment: SCAC l  Linear Ft l Weight

Answer (score 0):

My first comment would be to give the contact rules table a name and also name some of the columns, then use index() and match(), which should reduce the length of the expression and allow you to then add a test for "" using an if(), but without example data I'm not so sure.

Comment: is there anyway I can upload the workbook I am working on?

Comment: @JoshuaHouse https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post